# How to write a file with some variables in bash shell?

Tags: bash

I am trying to print variables to my file by using a sh file, but it doesn't work.
It is very simple code. How can I fix it? And I don't understand at a point. the script works in command as I expected. But it shows me totally different result when I move the scripts to a `sh` file.

```
#! /bin/bash
var=12345
echo -e "first sentence
second sentence
$var:$var th sentence
"
```

I expected

```
first sentence
second sentence
12345:12345 th sentence
```

but it shows me

```
first sentence
second sentence
 th sentence
```

Comment: script is correct and should work fine. Please recheck.

Comment: your code works correctly for me

Comment: Get rid of the `space` in `#! /bin/bash`

Comment: There's no difference @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: No but it looks wonky...

Comment: Please specify the operating system this script was tested on.

Comment: David, space before the shebang path is no more significant that anywhere else a command path is being executed. Some people prefer it to make the line clearer. Gavin's code is fine.  @Gavin, copy/paste from here to make a new file and see if that works. Make sure you aren't using a Windows editor that adds carriage returns or some such.

Answer (score 0):

You code is correct and valid.

```
~# bash s.sh
first sentence
second sentence
12345:12345 th sentence
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am such a junior to use linux. So do you think my linux is crazy? I am using centOS 7.

Comment: @GavinHwang no problem. you need more experience :) good luck

Answer (score 0):

The only other suggestion to make for multi-line output rather than using `echo` would be to use a *heredoc*. So long as you don't single-quote `'EOF'` normal variable expansion occurs, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

var=12345

cat << EOF
first sentence
second sentence
$var:$var th sentence
EOF
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash heredoc.sh
first sentence
second sentence
12345:12345 th sentence
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your code but it shows me.
# bash test.sh
test.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
test.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
')st.sh: line 9: warning: here-document at line 5 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF
first sentence
second sentence
 th sentence
EOF

Comment: Don't write bash scripts in Windows Editors - you filled the file with CRLF line-endings. Bash requires POSIX line-endings of `'\n'`, not DOS CRLF endings of `"\r\n"` -- that's why you see the complains about `'\r'`. What editor are you using? All modern editors (not Notepad) have the ability to choose the line ending you want. You should choose "Linux/Unix" line endings. If you have `dos2unix` you can fix your file with `dos2unix test.sh`.